# How to make a try catch in which the connection timeout is error

Tags: java, try-catch, katalon-studio

Im trying to create a try catch where Im trying to open a web and if I remove the connection, it would say Request Timeout Error

```
try{
    WebUI.openBrowser('link here')
}

catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Request Timeout Error");
}
```

I want the console to print Request Timeout Error when the link doesn't load

Comment: What does the documentation of the `WebUI.openBrowser` method say about what it does on timeout?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer!), please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can handle anything that comes up in the comments.